# Conjugation of verbs for できる

Tags: grammar

Why in the sentence [below](https://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E5%AC%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%88.html) the kanji 会 is not followed by う?

In my understanding, できる is attached to a verb in its Dictionary form, which in that case is 会う.

あなたに再**会**できてうれしい。'I am pleased to see you again.'

Comment: Have you looked up 再会?

Comment: My dictionary indicates that 再会 is a noun, or a suru verb. Can できる directly follow a noun (such as this one)?

Comment: Yes, it’s the potential form of する. By the way, it (or する) doesn’t immediately follow a dictionary form. 会うできる (or 会うする) would be ungrammatical.

Comment: So you obligatorily have が or ことが? I found this example あの人たちの赤ん坊 はもう歩くが出来る。

Comment: For a dictionary form you need ことが, not just が. Where did you find that sentence?

Comment: Here https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/their+baby+is+able+to+walk+already, but with the こと. It was a typo on my part. Thanks Leebo!

Comment: Note that が following the dictionary form of a verb means “but”.  It is the subject marker only when it follows a 体言 (such as こと).

Comment: @L.F. Sure, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the verb here is not 会う, but 再会する.

That said, the できる is the potential form of する. So 再会する is to meet again, and 再会できる is able to meet again.